# Switch case in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

This is my vb.net code:

```
  Private Function PartOK(ByVal sPart As String) As Boolean
    Dim sCheck As String
    sCheck = "1234567890"
    PartOK = False
    sPart = Trim(sPart)

    If (Len(sPart) = PART_LENGTH) Or (IsNumeric(sPart)) Then
        Select Case sPart
            Case New String("1", PART_LENGTH), New String("2", PART_LENGTH), New String("3", PART_LENGTH)
            Case New String("4", PART_LENGTH), New String("5", PART_LENGTH), New String("6", PART_LENGTH)
            Case New String("7", PART_LENGTH), New String("8", PART_LENGTH), New String("9", PART_LENGTH)
            Case New String("0", PART_LENGTH), Left(sCheck, PART_LENGTH), Left(StrReverse(Left(sCheck, PART_LENGTH)), PART_LENGTH)
            Case Else : PartOK = True
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

This function i converted into c#. but I did not understand the switch case.

Can you people explain that?

Comment: This...really doesn't make any sense as VB.NET code. What does it do, and why have you written it like so?

Comment: I realy dont understand what your question is? Do you want know what the switch case does? Or do you want to know how to convert it into C#?

Comment: I want to know how that switch case will work.

Comment: How do you know it *does* work? Who wrote the code? Where did you get it from? What is it *supposed* to do?

Answer (score 4):

This is a strong contender for the obfuscated code of the year award.  The C# *switch* statement doesn't have nearly the same flexibility as the VB.NET Select statement so a direct translation is not possible.  In this case, a good and fast substitute is a HashSet.  It ought to resemble something like this (assuming PART_LENGTH is 5):

```
    private static HashSet<string> badParts = new HashSet<string> { 
        "00000", "11111", "22222", "33333", "44444", "55555", 
        "66666", "77777", "88888", "99999", "01234", "98765" 
    };
```

Note that the Left() cases in your original code are probably a bug if PART_LENGTH is not 10.  You surely want to write code to fill it in but I left it like this to make it more visible what is being rejected.  Then testing the string becomes:

```
    public static bool PartOK(string part) {
        long partNumber;
        if (part.Length != badParts[0].Length) return false;
        if (!long.TryParse(part, out partNumber)) return false;
        if (badParts.Contains(part)) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: +1. If PART_LENGTH can vary at runtime, badParts could be built dynamically of course. Also the VB IsNumeric would allow strings with decimal points and exponentials, unlike long.TryParse. This may have been a bug in the original VB!

Answer (score 2):

> This function i converted into c#. but I did not understand the switch case.

I assume you mean that when you tried to convert it to C#, you received errors. It would have been useful to see the converted code and the errors, but never mind... It also doesn't help that your VB code doesn't even compile with Option Strict On.

In C#, `case` expressions have to be compile-time constants - and you can't specify ranges, or multiple values directly (you specify multiple cases). Basically, the C# switch/case statement is more restrictive than in VB.

It's not entirely clear what your code is *trying* to achieve, but in C# you'd almost certainly just have to use an if/else statement instead. Or even just a single expression:

```
// Names changed for sanity. You could use the VB IsNumeric function, or
// consider *exactly* what you want - int.TryParse, long.TryParse or
// decimal.TryParse may be appropriate. Also note that I've changed your "Or"
// into an "And" as that's the only thing that makes sense...
return part.Length == ValidPartLength && 
       IsNumeric(part)) &&
       part != new string(part[0], ValidPartLength) &&
       part != "1234567890".Substring(0, ValidPartLength) &&
       part != "0987654321".Substring(0, ValidPartLength);
```

Comment: Your c# expression is neat but doesn't match the VB? What about the ascending and descending sequences of characters (sCheck) "1234...N" and "N...321" where N is PART_LENGTH